# VSCode metals scala, integration tests folder does not see classes

Tags: scala, scala-metals

in folder `module/src/it` I have my integration tests, configured with sbt like in:

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Integration+Tests

but VSCode with metals shows me that does not see those classes, everything compiles fine with sbt. What can I do with it ? thanks!

edit:
rest of tests, main code etc works fine in vscode, only issue is with `it` tests folder

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like bloop does not support it and someone created ticket for them:

https://github.com/scalacenter/bloop/issues/1162

Answer (score -2):

The VS Code plugin uses by default the JAVA_HOME environment variable (via find-java-home) to locate the java executable. Metals only works with Java 8 so this executable cannot point to another version such as Java 11.

https://olafurpg.github.io/metals/docs/editors/vscode.html

Comment: ? and how this is related to my problem ? :D I have problem only with it folder, rest is working fine.